# Linq to xml - access deep element

Tags: c#, xml

In C# i need to access element that is nested in many other elements. I could write a query by naming all of elements but that would be very time consuming. Is there any easy way to do this or maybe some generator?

for example i have a xml:

> ```
>        <div id="list_offers">
>     <div class="container">
>       <div id="header">
>         <div class="row">
>           <div class="space-on-sides">
>             <div class="sixteen columns relative">
>               <div class="logo">
>                 <a href="/">
>                   <img src="/images/design_resp/design/logo_profesia.png" width="113" height="76" alt="PROFESIA.SK - prĂˇca, zamestnanie, ponuky prĂˇce, brigĂˇda, voÄľnĂ© pracovnĂ© miesto" title="PROFESIA.SK - prĂˇca, zamestnanie, ponuky prĂˇce, brigĂˇda, voÄľnĂ© pracovnĂ© miesto" />
>                 </a>
>               </div>
>               <div class="right-panel">
>                 <a class="login-company small red button nice radius right hide-on-phones margin-on-left" title="Vstup pre firmy" href="/login_person.php?action=company_login">Vstup pre firmy</a>
>                 <a class="login-company small red button nice radius right show-on-phones margin-on-left" href="/login_person.php?action=company_login">Firmy</a>
>                 <a rel="nofollow" id="login_modal" class="small gray button nice radius right" title="PrihlĂˇste sa do konta" href="/login_person.php?action=login">PrihlĂˇsiĹĄ</a>
>                 <div class="search">
>                   <div class="relative hide-on-phones">
>                     <form name="fulltextsearch" id="fulltextsearch" action="/search.php" method="get" onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('search').value=='HÄľadanie') return false; return true;" class="nice" />
>                     <input name="which_form" type="hidden" value="simple" />
>                     <input name="tab_name" type="hidden" />
>                     <input name="search_anywhere" type="text" id="search" placeholder="HÄľadanie" tabindex="1" class="input-text expand" />
>                     <input name="submit_search_simple" type="image" src="/images/design_resp/design/blank.png" alt="HÄľadaĹĄ" class="ico search-nosprite" />&lt;/form&gt;
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="show-on-phones">
>                     <a title="HÄľadajte ponuky prĂˇce podÄľa rĂ´znych kritĂ©riĂ">
>                     </a>
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="row-header-favorite">
>                   <div class="header-favorite">
>                     <a title="Moje vybranĂ© pracovnĂ© ponuky" class="ico-shopping-cart-toppanel" rel="nofollow" href="/user_details.php?action=show_my_offers&amp;ref_top_panel=157">0</a>
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>               </div>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> ```

and i need access:

> input name="tab_name" type="hidden"

Comment: You definitely need to look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Your xml/html is not valid. Some attributes are not properly enclosed by `"`s

Comment: sorry, now it should be ok

Comment: in c#, sorry i forgot mention that

Comment: Not sure if this will be a concern or not, but valid HTML is not always guaranteed to be valid XML. Of course, maybe you're generating this yourself so you can make sure that it's always valid, but it's something to be aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile); //XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

var input = xDoc.Descendants("input")
                .First(i=>(string)i.Attribute("name")=="tab_name");
```

XPath can be used too

```
var input = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//input[@name='tab_name']");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access that element on server side, you'll need to add a `runat` attribute there (like this: `runat="server"`), to make it a server side control. I would strongly suggest making it a control of your page, then, so you can access it like any other variable. You would have to give it an ID, so at the very least you could fetch it through that property.

But! your problem seems to be more client side related, so I strongly, really strongly suggest you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) instead. Get jQuery in your site, and it becomes as easy as:

```
$("input[name='tab_name']");
```

Or better yet, if you give it an ID:

```
$("#idYouGaveTotheField");
```

Comment: i have that xhtml in string variable. i would like to use c#