# Accessing XML elements using C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I'm having the program shown below:

[image: Program portion]

When the user selects a Client, and after specifying the date using the datePicker, the date should be added under the water request for the same user.

We might have more than one request for each client.

The structure of my XML file is as follows:

```
<clients>
    <record>
       <Name></Name>
       <Surname></Surname>
       <Mobile></Mobile>
       <Address></Address>
       <Request>
           <date></date>
       </Request>
     </record>
</clients>
```

Can you help me with this one please?

I've walked through this example:

```
 string xtitle = textBox1.Text.ToString();
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Book.xml");
 XElement element =
xmlDoc.Root.Elements("book").Where(r => (string)r.Element("Isbn") == xtitle).FirstOrDefault();
 if (element != null)
 {
 element.SetElementValue("Isbn", textBox1.Text);
 element.SetElementValue("Book_Name", textBox2.Text);
 element.SetElementValue("Price", textBox3.Text);
 element.SetElementValue("Date_of_Publication", textBox4.Text);
 element.SetElementValue("Number_of", textBox6.Text);
 element.SetElementValue("Category", textBox7.Text);
 }
 xmlDoc.Save("Book.xml");
```

Supposing that "ISBN" has another subelement, how can I access it?

Comment: You're looking for LINQ to XML.

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to access <date> within <Request> ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to xml - access deep element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983905/linq-to-xml-access-deep-element)

Comment: Because I have worked in villages where potable water was a scarce commodity, i am curious: is this like a class project or are you really doing an app to track real life requests for water?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would prefer to define the corresponding classes and objects and use an XML serializer constructed from them to read and save the file.

You would need to learn how to use the serializable interface.  Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Using that, you will create classes to hold the data objects that you would read from the xml file.  The structure of the classes will match the structure of your xml file, so that you will have a request class that just has a date property.  You will also have a "Client" class that has a collection of request objects as one of its properties, along with client name, etc.

Using the outermost class, you will construct an xml serializer which you can then use to deserialize (read from text/xml file into actual objects in memory) and serialize the file (save from the objects in memory back to a text/xml file.  This is just a couple of lines of code that you will find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In memory, you will have an array or a collection of Client objects.  You can then use LINQ to mess with that collection - insert, sort, delete.  You can bind your listbox to that collection to display its data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Book.xml");
You can use Linq to Xml to get the Request element and add the date node to it.

```
var requestDate = DateTime.Today; //Get the date from the date picker

var requestElement = xEle.Descendants("Request").FirstOrDefault();

if(requestElement != null)
{
    requestElement.Add(new XElement("date", requestDate));

    xmlDoc.Save("Book.xml");
}
```