# linq issue accessing deep xml data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to access xml data that's deep in an xml file with linq. I've been looking at these examples:
[linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983905/linq-to-xml-access-deep-element)
[linq](https://www.bytehide.com/blog/linq-xml-csharp)

I'm not seeing a good example that doesn't involve names.

**mid-question Update:**

Ideally, I should be able to access the conditions (1 or 2 usually), and for each condition, to check the Success Criteria against the day's current conditions. So it would provide the
buildMachine
ProcessName (get filename from that to check against)
Conditions (so can iterate/loop over if multiple)
path/VersionFile
SuccessCriteria (so can loop over if multiple)
field=, comparison=, value=

So far I have this code:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\.."));
string finalPathXml = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(newPath, @"BuildVerificationBuildAttributes.xml"));

//linq 

    XDocument xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Load(finalPathXml);
    XElement buildVerificationElement = xmlDoc1.Element("BuildVerification");
    IEnumerable<XElement> buildElements = buildVerificationElement.Elements("build");
    IEnumerable<XElement> buildMachines = buildElements.Elements("BuildMachine"); //works. Has build machine and info in it.
    
    //this doesn't work...all empty
    IEnumerable<XElement> processes = buildMachines.Elements("Process");
    IEnumerable<XElement> processNames = processes.Elements("ProcessName");
    IEnumerable<XElement> conditions = processNames.Elements("Conditions");

    foreach (XElement buildMachine in buildMachines)
    {
        //var cond1 = xmlDoc1.Descendants("")
        //foreach condition
      //{
      //path = 
      //for each success criteria
      //{
      //field=
      //comparison=
      //value=
      //}
      //}
      //for each BuildMachine, I need to obtain each condition(s) and it's subsequent dest path,
      // and success criteria/field/comparison/value. Then I can go and see if we meet the 
      //criteria for that machine and case.  I'm having trouble finding how to get those deeper 
      //info in the xml 
}
```

This is what my xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BuildVerification>
    <build>
        <BuildMachine>mach-31</BuildMachine>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                            **<SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>**
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename2.txt”</VersionFile>

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.h”</VersionFile>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>

        </build>
        
         <!-- Next -->
        <build>
        <BuildMachine>mach-46</BuildMachine>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.h”</VersionFile>

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.h”</VersionFile>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                            <field>Status</field>
                            <comparison>equal</comparison>
                            <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
                        
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>
                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                                <value>Success</value>
                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>

                                <SuccessCriteria>
                                    <field>Status</field>
                                    <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                    <value>Success</value>

                                </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinFileVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <VersionFile>”\\view\Build_NightlyDeveloper\filename.cs”</VersionFile>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            
            
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <ProductName>ABC</ProductName>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <ProductName>CDE</ProductName>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>SpinISProjectVersionStats</ProcessName>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition>
                            <ProductName>EFG</ProductName>

                            <SuccessCriteria>
                                <field>Status</field>
                                <comparison>equal</comparison>
                                <value>Success</value>

                            </SuccessCriteria>
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
            </Process>

        </build>
</BuildVerification>
```

**Update2:**
My attempt using the response method below, with my changes to get first and last, and how to access what I get out of the xml with a variable is below.  What would I do if I had 3 Processes or 3 SuccessCriteria?

```
var results = xmlDoc1.Descendants("build")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("Process")
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Build_Machine = (string)x.Element("BuildMachine"),
        Process_Name1 = (string)y.Descendants("ProcessName").FirstOrDefault(),
        Process_Name2 = (string)y.Descendants("ProcessName").Last(),
        VersionFile = (string)y.Descendants("VersionFile").FirstOrDefault(),
        Field1 = (string)y.Descendants("field").FirstOrDefault(),
        Comparison1 = (string)y.Descendants("comparison").FirstOrDefault(),
        Value1 = (string)y.Descendants("value").FirstOrDefault(),
        Field2 = (string)y.Descendants("field").Last(),
        Comparison2 = (string)y.Descendants("comparison").Last(),
        Value2 = (string)y.Descendants("value").Last()
    })).ToList();
foreach (var cur in results)
{
    string buildMach = (string)cur.Build_Machine;
    string p1 = (string)cur.Process_Name1;
    string p2 = (string)cur.Process_Name2;
    string verFile = (string)cur.VersionFile;
    string f1 = (string)cur.Field1;
    string f2 = (string)cur.Field2;
    string c1 = (string)cur.Comparison1;
    string c2 = (string)cur.Comparison2;
    string v1 = (string)cur.Value1;
    string v2 = (string)cur.Value2;
}
```

Comment: Is LINQ a requirement? Since your XML is a known structure and doesn't appear to deviate, wouldn't it be easier to deserialize the XML into a class?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I added a mid-question update to with info on what I need from the program.  Since there are repeating conditions and build machines and success criteria, I need to iterate over each one to make sure I find all of them

Comment: @Middas - we don't want it as a class because there are varying successCriteria, Conditions, and buildMachines. Plus I want it in a format that they can add to or edit in case things change. They aren't developers.

Comment: @dbc - how do I access these inner xml data so I can extract and compare (success) with what I find each day in the build output.

Comment: @Michele - Your update code is really weird to me. I would never write it like that. I'm still struggling to understand what you're trying to do. Can you help clarify what the intent of your problem is?

Comment: @enigmativity - we have scm builds that we have logs from.  Every day we compare our success criteria for each log with our list of what success is.  This success criteria is in my xml file.  I am automating getting the success criteria out of the xml so I can compare it with what I get out of the build log.  What I have so far doesn't account for multiple (1-3+) Processes that I have under a given build tag. I'm not sure at this point how to account for varying xml depth, or even obtain the criteria for 2 as well as 1 and 3 which would be the case with my Update2.

Comment: @Michele - What does "doesn't account for multiple (1-3+) Processes" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity - if you look closely at my xml I have (varying number of) multiple nested Process tags under it's enclosing tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{

    class Program
    {
        static string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("build")
                .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("Process")
                .SelectMany(y => y.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
                .Select(z =>  new
                {
                    Build_Machine = (string)x.Element("BuildMachine"),
                    Process_Name = (string)y.Element("ProcessName"),
                    VersionFile = (string)y.Descendants("VersionFile").FirstOrDefault(),
                    Field = (string)z.Element("field"),
                    Comparison = (string)z.Element("comparison"),
                    Value = (string)z.Element("value")
                }))).ToList();
 
        }
 

    }

}
```

Results

[image]

Comment: if I wanted to grab the values from results so I can compare them with logs to determine if the build is successful, how would I do that? Like if mach31, SpinFileVersionStats field=Status, how do I retrieve that mach31 field from results so I can compare with something not shown here?

Comment: there are cases where the xml has more than one Process/name under a Build Machine. Is your results missing the second process/name because of the FirstOrDefault?

Comment: See Update2 in the question for my try, and additional question.

Comment: No.  It is due to using descendants which gets an array.  There is only one process name for each process so all rows will be returned.  The FirstOrDefault just is taking an array of 1 item and converting to a singleton.

Comment: @Michele :  x.Descendants("Process") is getting every process so you do not miss any data.  I just had to use descendants because object were not immediate children and had to convert the array to a singleton.

Comment: there is a case where I have 2 successCriteria in a row in the xml. I missed adding it in my example xml so it's towards the top. I don't think your code would pick that up?

Comment: thank you so much! I wish I could give you +extra.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Please try the following conceptual solution.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\Michele.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    
    foreach (var elem in xdoc.Descendants("SuccessCriteria"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("field='{0}', comparison='{1}', value='{2}'",
            elem.Element("field")?.Value,
            elem.Element("comparison")?.Value,
            elem.Element("value")?.Value);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
field='Status', comparison='equal', value='Success'
...
```